# Spring @Cacheable doesn't retry on error from Jedis/Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

Spring @Cacheable doesn't retry on error from Jedis/Redis.

We have errors during data read:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cluster retry deadline exceeded.; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterOperationException: Cluster retry deadline exceeded.
```

error is not handled by @Cacheable annotation (i'd expect to get data from annonated method in case of an error)

```
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.findById(Unknown Source:0)
```

I can see  that there is `void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key)`

but I don't see any parameters that would help me to retrieve data from original method/source (fallback behaviour)

How to handle it ?  It looks like that @Cacheable is not very usable in case of cache errors (Do i need to implement my own bespoke code using RedisTemplate etc. ? )